# How do I Sum Parts of A Whole and Display the Sum with Each Part in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

this is completely stumping me. Just like the question states, I want to sum pieces of a whole and then display the sum with each part. In more specific terms, I have several portfolios, and each has several accounts. I want to sum the account quantities for each portfolio and then display the portfolio qunatity in each line to compare against the account quantity. What I have so far is as follows

```
select PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION, SECURITY, CUSIP, ACT_QTTY, 
  SUM(ACT_QTTY) as PORTFOLIO_QTTY 
from psc_filled_orders 
where TRADE_DATE_INT > 20170601 
group by PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION, SECURITY, CUSIP, ACT_QTTY
```

I read a few questions about sums and two questions about running sums, but what I'm looking for is neither of these. Think you could help me out?

In very general terms I want my result to look like this:

```
Portfolio | Account | Account Quantity | Portfolio Quantity
-----------------------------------------------------------
Port 1    | Act A   | 300              | 700
Port 1    | Act B   | 200              | 700
Port 1    | Act C   | 200              | 700
Port 2    | Act A   | 800              | 500
Port 2    | Act B   | -300             | 500
```

Sometimes the account names are reused like in my example, sometimes they are unique, the portfolio names are always unique. Quantities are both positive and negative.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for wrapping the code snippit.

Comment: How you can have Account Quantity `-300` ?

Comment: the account can be overdrawn, the assets in the account can be held short, there are several reasons.

Comment: A result set with no data set is... well anyway, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```sql
SELECT a.PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION, ACT_QTTY, PORTFOLIO_QTTY 
  FROM (
    SELECT PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION, SUM(ACT_QTTY) AS ACT_QTTY 
      FROM psc_filled_orders 
     WHERE TRADE_DATE_INT > 20170601 
     GROUP BY PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION
) a JOIN (
  SELECT PORTFOLIO, SUM(ACT_QTTY) AS PORTFOLIO_QTTY
    FROM psc_filled_orders 
   WHERE TRADE_DATE_INT > 20170601
   GROUP BY PORTFOLIO
) p
   ON a.PORTFOLIO = p.PORTFOLIO
```

Sample output:

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------+----------------+
| PORTFOLIO | ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION | ACT_QTTY | PORTFOLIO_QTTY |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+----------------+
| Port 1    | Act A               |      300 |            700 |
| Port 1    | Act B               |      200 |            700 |
| Port 1    | Act C               |      200 |            700 |
| Port 2    | Act A               |      800 |            500 |
| Port 2    | Act B               |     -300 |            500 |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+----------------+
```

---

You may also consider `WITH ROLLUP` which gives you a slightly different output but meant exactly for this (calculating subtotals for each grouping level and a grand total)

```sql
SELECT PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION, SUM(ACT_QTTY) AS ACT_QTTY 
  FROM psc_filled_orders 
 WHERE TRADE_DATE_INT > 20170601 
 GROUP BY PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION WITH ROLLUP
 HAVING PORTFOLIO IS NOT NULL -- this is to remove the grand total
```

Which will give you

```
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| PORTFOLIO | ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION | ACT_QTTY |
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
| Port 1    | Act A               |      300 |
| Port 1    | Act B               |      200 |
| Port 1    | Act C               |      200 |
| Port 1    | NULL                |      700 | - this is subtotal for Port 1
| Port 2    | Act A               |      800 |
| Port 2    | Act B               |     -300 |
| Port 2    | NULL                |      500 | - this is subtotal for Port 2
+-----------+---------------------+----------+
```

---

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e5156f067e1cac0d26f182535b7b29cb) demo for both queries

Comment: WITH ROLLUP you say? This is getting closer. I might have to edit the question. I've tried some of these solutions but because my whole problem is a little more sophisticated, I might have to bring out the whole thing.

Comment: Your first solution is almost perfect but due to my own inability, I can't extend your solution to exactly what I need. There is a third parameter that I have excluded, hoping that I would be able to implement it later. The third parameter is an ID number; each account can hold many different items and the summation is actually only taken over the ID numbers, but is separated by both account and portfolio. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean. Can you show sample data and the actual desired outcome?

Comment: I didn't use the whole problem, and I needed to show more data to create the same issue that I had. Eventually I solved the problem, but you did solve the problem I presented so I'm marking your answer as the correct one

Answer (score -1):

Double check the join on the subquery is correct. I'm not sure what ID you are using.

```
select pfo.PORTFOLIO
,pfo.ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION
,pfo.SECURITY
,pfo.CUSIP
,pfo.ACT_QTTY
,(SELECT SUM(ACT_QTTY) FROM psc_filled_orders where pfo.cusip = cusip and TRADE_DATE_INT > 20170601) as PORTFOLIO_QTTY 
from psc_filled_orders pfo
where pfo.TRADE_DATE_INT > 20170601 
group by pfo.PORTFOLIO, pfo.ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION, pfo.SECURITY, pfo.CUSIP, pfo.ACT_QTTY
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this
select PORTFOLIO, ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION, SECURITY, CUSIP, ACT_QTTY, 
  SUM(ACT_QTTY) OVER (Partition by PORTFOLIO) as PORTFOLIO_QTTY 
from psc_filled_orders 
where TRADE_DATE_INT > 20170601